# beans in a jar, org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a Spring Boot app that persists some beans of the format:

```
package my.package;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
public class MyBean{

   @Id
   public long id;

   //getters and setters removed for the sake of space

}
```

to a MySql db.

I want to share these bean definitions with multiple applications so I put them in a jar file and compiled the jar into my Spring Boot app.

When I run, I get an UnsatisfiedDependencyException during the creation of my MyBeanRepository (defined in my Spring Boot app).

It tells me the MyBean is "Not an managed type: class my.package.MyBean"

What did I do wrong and what do I have to do to convince Spring this is ok?

Comment: I guess you are using CDI. This is an entity which cannot be injected into a bean unless you make it a managed bean by annotating appropriately like `@Named`, `@RequestScoped` (or its stereotype `@Model`) but it is dependent upon the requirement.

Comment: What is CDI?  Do I put those annotations on the bean definition in the jar or in the spring boot app?

Comment: Since you are using Spring, you can ignore that comment and those annotations, those won't help you.

Comment: Have you made sure, that Spring Boot can detect your entity (by specifying the packages in the EntityScan annotation)?

Comment: No, I haven't.  I will give that a try and let you know what happens.

Comment: @dunni EntityScan does not cause my entity to be detected.

Comment: Please post the errors and the related code.